# appending a text file that contains any string with an '@' with php

Tags: php, html

I have no idea how you would edit a text file with  lines that are either an email or a line that does not contain an email. So the only thing identify what you want is the @...

So my thought is to output a table inside a form with two columns, one for the email and another with a radio selector that allows me to append the email to the left of the radio button. Can anyone feel me on this?

Is there a better way to get this done? Maybe when they originally inputted have some sort of hidden id?

Not sure how you would do that with just the @ for a key... And no telling how many emails there will be.

alertmon_user.txt looks something like this

```
#fjkdslafjkdsla
#fjdlksajfdlksa
#jfdlksa
test@test.com
two@jfdslk.com
three@fjsld.com
```

and this script works great for separating the email addresses from the stuff I don't want.

```
<?php
$search = '@';
$lines = file('alertmon_user.txt');
foreach($lines as $line)
{
if(strpos($line, $search) !== false)
echo $line;
}
?>
```

So my output now looks like this

test@test.com two@jfdslk.com three@fjsld.com

Here's how I processed the form to get the email to the text file...

```
<?php
$txt = "alertmon_user.txt"; 
if (isset($_POST['field1'])) { 
$fh = fopen($txt, 'a'); 
$txt = $_POST['field1']; 
fwrite($fh,$txt . PHP_EOL); 
fclose($fh); 
}
?>
```

Any creative ideas on how I can edit 1 or all of the email addresses, no matter how many they are? Or do I need another approach?

I feel like I'm painting my way into a corner?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't really get what you want us to tell you, you have a file with emails in it and you want to parse it, that's it ?

Comment: I need to be able to edit the emails

Comment: ordinarily i would echo a php statement in the value of an input box and process that form with the changes. However this is way more complicated for my grade level anyway.

Comment: When you have an email you can use the "explode" method to split the string to get the part before the @ and after it, that's why you're looking for?

Comment: What is the original big picture problem you are trying to solve?  It seems like you are trying to use a chainsaw to cut paper.

Comment: Hi Tim, I agree I'm trying to use a chansaw to cut paper. The text file has two types of inputs. The engineers notes that the engineers precedes with a '#' and then the client inputs emails that adds a new item and a line break. The trick now is to be able to edit the emails.. That''s my problem.